# Error on Uploading Document and Picking Up People in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document, people-picker

I recently implement Sharepoint 2013 on my Server . i found that when i want to upload document or Pick people with People Picker i have this error:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        System.ServiceModel 4.0.0.0
Date:          11/29/2014 2:25:44 AM
Event ID:      3
Task Category: WebHost
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          CCI\sp-farm
Computer:      Portal.CCI.Local
Description:
WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information:         System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/17010420
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service     '/_vti_bin/client.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The    exception message is: A binding instance has already been associated to listen URI    'http://portal.cci.local/_vti_bin/client.svc'. If two endpoints want to share the same    ListenUri, they must also share the same binding object instance. The two conflicting   endpoints were either specified in AddServiceEndpoint() calls, in a config file, or a   combination of AddServiceEndpoint() and config. . ---> System.InvalidOperationException: A   binding instance has already been associated to listen URI 'http://portal.cci.local/_vti_bin/client.svc'. If two endpoints want to share the same   ListenUri, they must also share the same binding object instance. The two conflicting endpoints were either specified in AddServiceEndpoint() calls, in a config file, or a   combination of AddServiceEndpoint() and config. 
   at    System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription    description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHost.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
  at     System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
  at  System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at            System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String     normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
      at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String       relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Delete Duplicate Binding in IIS Website

Please Visit this link:

http://royaltutorials.com/a-binding-instance-has-already-been-associated-to-listen-uri/